# Hacer consulta mysql al cargar pagina y mostrar resultado en un modal

Tags: php, mysql, modal

Requiero que al cargar una página html se haga una consulta a la base de datos mysql, y constatar si el valor dentro de un campo es 0 (0 negado, 1 autorizado); para luego mostrar un modal indicando que se debe realizar completar el registro para la autorización de acceso. Además, que el modal se muestre cada hora hasta que el valor del campo sea 1 y no se vuelva a mostrar.

He intentado varias cosas infructuosamente, y requiero de su gran ayuda

Aquí parte del script que tengo para mostrar el modal cada hora

```
<?php
$muestraModal = false;
if(!isset($_COOKIE["verModal"])) {
$expirar = 3600;
setcookie('verModal', 'SI', (time() + $expirar));
$muestraModal = true;
}
?>

<div class="modal fade" id="mdlInicio">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

if($exibirModal === true) { ?>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    // id del modal
    $("#mdlInicio").modal("show");
   });
  </script>
  <?php
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Falta información en tu pregunta: ¿cómo pasas los datos al servidor? ¿están llegando dichos datos? ¿cómo conectas a la base de datos? ¿cómo obtienes los datos en el servidor? ¿cómo los devuelves al cliente? ¿qué errores tienes?

Comment: A. Cedaño, ya lo he resuelto; al cargar la pagina se ejecuta una función con php que consulta la información en la bbdd, para luego, a través de una condicional cargar el modal. Gracias por el interés

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto la dificultad haciendo una consulta a la base de datos, y utilizando la condicional if-else, constato el contenido del campo, y así, dependiendo del resultado 
 debe mostrar el modal o no.

Ésta es la consulta que ejecuto al cargar la pagina:

```
function getCorpsys() {
  $mysqli=conectaSQL();
  $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
  $query=$mysqli->query("SELECT * from tblcorpsystem");
  while ($array=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($array['corpIsReg']==0) {
      echo "Aqui coloque el script que muestra el modal cada hora";
    }
  }
  return $corpo;
  $desconectaSQL;
}
```

Y así he resuelto mis dudas.